# Send email to multiple users without having to enter them one by one?

Tags: gmail

Using Gmail, how can you send an email to several contacts without having to enter their emails one by one?

I cannot seem to figure out an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Go to your contacts and create labels.

Then group your contacts by labeling them.**

Now **when composing a new email** instead of adding the contacts one by one you can **use the label name**.
All the contacts under the selected label will be auto added.

Adding multiple labels, **all contacts under each label will be added**.